# variable range in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any simple method to make one side of the range a variable?

```
function myFunction() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RXJ9uR9oDV0gEL7ZyLtSi-WqFxk5Pg-7oitViHZOyf8");
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

//This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet

 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);

// add values in the last cells and calc the sum

 var cellTotal = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, lastColumn - 1);
 var cellTotalVal = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, lastColumn);
 cellTotal.setValue('total').setFontWeight("bold");

 //here I try a numorous options to get my range right 
 cellTotalVal.setFormula("=SUM(D1:CONCATENATE('D', lastRow))");

};
```

What I want to achieve here is a `SUM` where the first value is D1 and the last is a `var` named `lastCell`.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the range open:

```
=SUM(D1:D)
```

will get you the entire column.

```
=SUM(D5:D)
```

will get you from D5 to the last row.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, this is what you are looking to do:

```
cellTotalVal.setFormula("=SUM(D1:D" + lastRow + ")");
```

This will create a string where assuming lastRow = 100, the string is "=SUM(D1:D100)"

Comment: Yeah, that one I found elsewhere before. I am asking this because it's more like a learning exercise for me. I am new to GS and curious if it is possible at all to use a variable in ranges or sums because I couldn't find it in Google Ref.

Comment: Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript, so the syntax applies.  For generic items such as this, also search for JavaScript answers. See my Edit above for my understanding of your comment, @Kuba88

Comment: Thanks Karl! I wasted the whole afternoon searching for different ways of doing it, now I can move on. Your code solves the issue. I didn't know where to put the space when concatenating...

Comment: You are welcome, @Kuba88 The Concatenate() portion is not necessary since your script is doing that for you.  If just for the exercise, you could include it as well, as I am guessing you may have figured out.